How to preserve deep link parameter after app installation?
I found a nice GitHub repo that covers deep linking in .NET MAUI here: https://github.com/Redth/MAUI.AppLinks.Sample
I understand that if a user doesn’t have the app installed, the “deep linking” will automatically send the user to the appropriate App Store depending on the platform.
My question is: if the user doesn't already have the app installed, is it possible to have a parameter as part of the deep link that the app can pick up once it's installed? The key point is making sure the parameter would be preserved and can be picked up by the app once the installation process is done.
As I understand it, this was the promise of, now deprecated, Firebase Dynamic Links. Just want to see if this is possible and if so, how I can implement it.

The described concept is generally referred to as "Deferred Deep Linking" or "Dynamic Linking". And, this is fairly complex process. Since, we are trying to send data/parameter to app before it's installation.
As you mentioned Firebase Dynamic Links provides this service, and it is now deprecated and will shut down on August 25, 2025 more...
There are other third party alternatives for deep-linking solutions that support .NET MAUI
One of well know service is Branch
For more information and implementation you can visit there documentation for MAUI here...
Implementing own deferred deep linking mechanism is not easy, that's the reason there are only paid third party service providers for this. That too for a cross platform framework like MAUI. It's even harder. Since we have to handle both platform's mechanism separately.
Hey, But

It always seems impossible until it’s done.

Here are some useful resources that will helpful in implementing own deferred deep linking

Deferred Deep Linking: How it works internally
This article discusses in-depth analysis of the mechanisms enabling deferred deep linking on Android and iOS platforms. It discusses the use of Android's Install Referrer API and Content Providers, as well as iOS's Universal Links and SKStoreProductViewController, to facilitate deep linking even when the app isn't installed.
[iOS] Implementing Deferred Deep Links with Clipboard
This explores a method for achieving deferred deep linking on iOS by utilizing the clipboard to store and retrieve deep link information during the app installation process.

I will keep updating this answer, If i found anything.

I appreciate your response. I really would like to implement this myself without using a paid service. Would you be able to give me some links to documentation or articles on how to implement deferred deep links in .NET MAUI? Thanks again!

@Sam check my updated answer. There isn't much available related to this topic. That's because probably no one would have done this before. Anyway, Good luck to you if you decide to implement this.

I really appreciate your response. I’ll keep the question open, hoping I’ll get more responses but I’ve already upvoted your answer. If I don’t get any other replies, I’ll mark yours as the answer. Thanks again!
